# Why have 2 events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I implemented [spectrum color picker](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/), and I'm trying to understand why is there 2 separate events performing the same thing?

[Source](https://github.com/bgrins/spectrum/blob/master/spectrum.js#L457-L476)

```
function paletteElementClick(e) {
    if (e.data && e.data.ignore) {
        set($(e.target).closest(".sp-thumb-el").data("color"));
         move();
    } else {
        set($(e.target).closest(".sp-thumb-el").data("color"));
         move();
          updateOriginalInput(true);
           if (opts.hideAfterPaletteSelect) {
               hide();
           }
        }
        return false;
}

var paletteEvent = IE ? "mousedown.spectrum" : "click.spectrum touchstart.spectrum";
paletteContainer.on(paletteEvent, ".sp-thumb-el", paletteElementClick);
initialColorContainer.on(paletteEvent, ".sp-thumb-el:nth-child(1)",  { ignore: true }, paletteElementClick);
```

Comment: For browser compatibility, As you can see IE supports `"mousedown.spectrum"` event whereas other browsers support `"click.spectrum touchstart.spectrum"` event

Comment: I mean there are 2 events. 1 for `paletteContainer`, and another for `initialColorContainer`, but they both access the same children.

Comment: Those are two different parent elements, getting a delegated event handler attached to them, calling the same function

Comment: @adeneo Right, but aren't the children the same?

Comment: Not neccessarely, that depends on your HTML, there's no reason the two different parent elements can't have completely different children elements, with the same class ?

Comment: @adeneo I don't get it. Can you please explain it to me using this example: http://jsfiddle.net/eLf76cfy/

Comment: No, but I can show you a simple example of why the children aren't neccessarely the same -> **http://jsfiddle.net/xmnybhe7/**